# Another confusion related to the concept of "Interpretation". Please see

Tags: c++, compilation, interpreter

I'll illustrate the doubt in my mind by using the following example I came up with.

Consider a C++ code written below :

```
#include<iostream.h>

void main()
{
 cout<<"LULZ \n";
 cout<<"\n Enter anything\n";
 int a;
 cin>>a;

 goto noexistence; 

}
```

Now, my question is that how will the output to the end user will differ if this piece of code is compiled and then, in a different case, interpreted? When we'll compile it, it will give a compile time error and will complain that no such label exists (noexistence).

But what will happen when this piece of code is interpreted? I don't know if there is an interpreter out there for C/C++ (I heard about CINT ROOT from CERN but I don't know how to operate it) but theoretically speaking, how would interpretation catch this fallacy where the label is not defined?

I am asking this question because I've read a lot of times that in interpretation, "the code is executed line by line". I could never grasp this notion of "line by line". Can anyone shed some light on it as this question is eating me right now hehe.

Comment: If it is CINT it will probably fall over in an a heap.

Comment: It depends on how this interpreter works. There is no "right answer" since there is no standard C++ interpreter. If you want to see how CINT does it, try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interpreter reads the input code and quickly parses it before execution.

Sometimes, parsing is just reading lines into a linked list. If this is all parsing an interpreter implements, then it would start scanning all input lines for the goto label and would print an error saying label not found.

A smarter interpreter can create a jump table as it proceeds executing for the lines already executed. In this case, the label can be searched in this table (for backward references) and also scanned in the following lines (for forward references).

Another interpreter can choose to parse all token in all input, and create a jump table before running the first statement. Such an interpreter would only check the jump table and print out an error message.

So it really all depends. However, a compiler parses, and compiles the input into an executable before any execution attempt.

Comment: Thanks, so this illustrates that the "line by line" as people say isn't a strictly "read line by line and execute" thing but can be much more sophisticated approach depending on the interpreter.

Comment: yes, it can be simpler or more complex. I guess it is also possible to write an interpreter that actually reads and executes a single line, but then scanning for labels would require reading the file from the beginning again.

Comment: Thank you! That was my exact doubt! Actually my misconception began after reading the following answer on one of my earlier questions related to interpretation on stackoverflow :

" 
 

Interpreters interpret code line by line, and decides the machine code at run time;

Compiler consume code by chunk, and decides the machine code at compile time;

"

But now it's cleared and thanks to you.

Comment: I would say, an interpreter executes statements using a software state machine while a compiler transforms them into machine code for hardware execution.

Comment: Was this question really a stupid one for which it has been marked as "useless"? Because if it seriously is a stupid question then I'll delete it (if it's possible)...

Comment: It will get closed if people think its useless, you don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read things about [compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), [interpreters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29), [bytecodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_code), [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++)

The C++ standard does not tell about how a C++ program gets executed. You could do that in your head (or with pencil and paper), you could use a bunch of human slaves (but that is unethical), you could use magic to have the C++ program executed. Most people use a compiler and a computer.

You could have an interpreter for C++

Practically and historically, C++ has evolved from C with the main (untold) assumption that it could be somehow compiled with real compilers for real hardware.

And interpreters and compilers is not a black & white distinction; there are intermediate ways (notably translating to a byte code or an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), then interpreting that).

I certainly won't define "interpreter" as something working line by line. Most interpreters don't work that way. THey usually read and parse an entire "function" at least.

Comment: It's okay, don't bother making edits. Your line "Did you read any thing about compilers, interpreters, bytecodes, C++" has made me feel so guilty now of being a bad uneducated boy that I am ashamed I asked this question in the first place. You, sir, are the master of concepts and how dare did I ask such a stupid question?

Comment: It was not meant to make you guilty, just to give appropriate references. Stack Overflow is usually a place to ask questions related to source code, for which you already searched or tried things.